# How do I make a custom control property with which Scene Builder can interact?

Tags: java, properties, custom-controls, javafx-8, scenebuilder

When I look at a Label in SceneBuilder, I see this:

[image]

This affects the text that is present in the Label control.

How can I create something similar for a custom control with a label inside it, so that I can directly access the custom control label text properties on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: If you expose the properties as JavaFX observable properties in the control, they should automatically appear in the properties pane in SceneBuilder (under the "Custom") section.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: The example in your previous question does this...

Comment: So just declaring the property does the trick?

Comment: Seems so: I think it has to follow the [FX properties pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107)

Comment: So it does. Thanks again, you've been invaluable.